# Android File Object? :D

Tags: android, file, oop

So i was watching [thenewboston](http://www.thenewboston.com) android tut's and i got confuse in this code :

Let's say i want to create a `FileOutputStream` Object, and we can do just by like this :

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

But there's a constructor for `FileOutputStream` like this :

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(YOUR_FILE_NAME);
```

So i have read some reference's that said in the firs line of code i just created an unuseable Object because we just created an object but we don't set it to anything.
We can use the second line of code because it's already a "completed" Object because i have created it with it's constructor.

My question is :  WHY IS THE FIRST LINE OF CODE WORKING?

Thanks All!

NOTE : English is not my native languange, so sorry if i made some mistake's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the documentation of [openFileOutput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) - it creates the file, if it does not exist. The first line works, because it's compliant with the API.

Comment: Thanks Sir :D
I got confuse with the documentation... that's why i'm asking alot, maybe my experience is not enough, or maybe i'm lack of English :D